# Rails way to make a horizontal menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to ask you about best rails way to create a menu.
I should to make a horizontal menu. Every page belongs to the specific item of this menu and this item should has id="current" when user opens on this page.

```
<ul>
  <li id="current">Home</li>
  <li>About us</li>
</ul>
```

As I understand I should to create a special helper which will create this html markup and use this helper with special parameter on every view of every page. Maybe there is a better rails way to do this?

---

PS. Update

My solution:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :open_most_important

  protected
    def open_most_important
      @menu = {  
        :cases => { :name => 'Cases', :link => '/cases'}, 
        :groups => { :name => 'Groups', :link => '/groups' }, 
        :projects => { :name => 'Projects', :link => '/projects' }, 
        :settings => { :name => 'Settings', :link => '/settings' }, 
        :about => { :name => 'About us', :link => '/about' }}
      @current_menu_item = :cases
    end
```

The fragment of the layout `application.html.erb`:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <% @menu.each do |item, value| -%>
      <% if @current_menu_item == item -%>
        <li id="current"><a href="<%= value[:link] %>"><%= value[:name] %></a></li>
      <% else -%>
        <li><a href="<%= value[:link] %>"><%= value[:name] %></a></li>
      <% end -%>
    <% end -%>
  </ul>
</div>
```

After I need to set `@current_menu_item` for every controller in the `before_filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want this menu to appear on every page. If that is the case you can just add it to your layout. If you don't understand layouts read up on them at Ruby on Rails Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#customizing-the-layout

Comment: Yes, I have the layout already. The problem is that menu (which now stored in the layout) should look differently for each page.

Comment: When you say look differently do you mean just a different style, or rather different links? You can probably use nested layouts in anycase, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do a menu. Though that is the funtionality that is implemented on this guide. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts

Answer (score 0):

This is how I tend to do it:

```
<%= menu_item("Home", root_path) {
      controller.controller_name == "pages" &&
      controller.action_name = "home" } %>
<%= menu_item("About us", page_path("about") {
      controller.controller_name == "pages" &&
      controller.action_name == "about" } %>
```

The helper:

```
def menu_item(name, url, options = {})
  if yield
    options["id"] = "current"
  end

  link_to name, url, options
end
```

The `"id"` will be `"current"` if the block passed to `menu_item` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle it is to put this in a navigation partial:

```
<%= nav_link "All Users", users_path, active_tabs.include?('all_users') %>
<%= nav_link "Add User", new_user_path, active_tabs.include?('add_user') %>
```

And then this helper at the top of each view:

```
<%= nav 'nav_partials/users_tabs', 'all_users' %> # one view
<%= nav 'nav_partials/users_tabs', 'add_user' %> # another view
```

And the helpers:

```
  def nav_link(title, path, active, options = {})
    if active
      options[:class] ? options[:class] += " active" : options[:class] = "active"
    end
    link_to(title, path, options)
  end

  def nav(partial, *active_tabs)
    partial = "#{params[:controller]}/nav_partials/#{partial}" unless partial.chars.first == '/'
    render :partial => partial, :locals => { :active_tabs => active_tabs }
  end
```

To me, it is elegant, even though there are some things that could be a bit better (like the file path thing in the `nav` helper, as well as referencing params in the helper). But it works very nicely, and it's very flexible.